# Consumable vs non-consumable

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have two apps connected to each other.

The functionality of app1 is: Users using app1 can share data with app2 users by paying them.

The functionality of app2 is: Users using app2 can access data from app1 by paying and requesting them to share.
And we use in-app purchases here.
So, please give me confirmation whether to use consumable or non-consumable.

Comment: Does **user1** of `app1` pay to your company or to the **user2** of `app2` ?? Explain same for vice-versa.

Comment: yes @dahiya_boy user1 of app1 pay to our compay to share his data with user2 and since user2 of app2 donot contain any data, so he ask user1 of app1 to provide his data. In this case user2 also pay to our company for asking user1 data

Comment: then you oeed to edit your ques n be more specific, bcz with your ques in sounds like both user pay to each other.\

Answer (score 2):

If your users can **pay each other multiple times for the same item** (think coins, credits, etc.) then use **consumable**.

If your users would only **pay each other once to unlock content forever** (photo filters, etc.) then use **non-consumable**.

Comment: Is there was way to get if the items are non-consumable vs consumable in swift (the code itself)? But this I mean in itunes it categories by consumable and non-consumable, can I get that 'property' in swift, so that I can manipulate my view accordingly?